# phpMyAdmin 'edit' and 'copy' links in grid view are missing where_clause as primary key is not detected properly error 1064

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a bit lost on this one. I recently set up MySQL and phpMyAdmin on a new computer. I have created databases and added content from a backup, and programatically. I have just tried to edit and copy a row within phpMyAdmin. When I click the links I get an Error saying there is 1064 with the sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`tablename` WHERE ;
```

I can see there is no column referenced in the SQL, but I can't work out why. I know I have unique and primary keys set up, and the schema works on other servers. It must be something wrong with my phpMyAdmin setup but I can't work out what. 
Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

**Update**

- This still happens on the latest version of phpMyAdmin
- This only happens in Tables with names starting with an uppercase character.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with SQL rather than the GUI? Might help determine where the issue is, if you can submit the SQL commands..

Comment: The correct sql command works. e.g. SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`tbname` WHERE id = 1; would bring back the correct record

Comment: I hope you are running the latest phpMyAdmin version (currently 4.5.2).

Comment: Currently on 4.5.1 the latest version available in home-brew. Is this an issue with 4.5.1? I haven't found anyone else with the same issue

Comment: Have just installed downloaded 4.5.2 and have exactly the same problem

Comment: The problem only exists on tables created outside of phpMyAdmin

Comment: Are you on OS X? See https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11669

Comment: I am on OSX. The settings for lower_case_file_system and lower_case_table names are different to how they were on my last Mac. And I am unable to change them, so the solution I have used is to rename all table names to use lower case, as is best practice. Should have done it this way to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of completing this question. The answer in this case was that table names must not start with an uppercase character. As soon as I changed to lower case the rows were editable

Answer (score 0):

You must have a primary key to see the Edit, Copy, and Delete links.  Edit your table by adding a new primary key (auto-increment), and after saving your changes, go back to the list of rows.  You will see the links again.

Comment: In this case primary keys were present. The answer in this case was changing tables names to lower case